# Can't connect to amazon rds

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pgadmin, prisma

I just setup aws rds and I'm trying to connect pgadmin to it. I put in the `Endpoint` and the `port` shown in the rds dashboard, and the username and password I set. When I try connecting, I get an error message saying: `Unable to connect to server "host name" port "port" failed: timeout expired.`

I also tried connecting prisma to it by running `npx prisma migrate dev --name init` and I also get an error saying `P1001: Can't reach database server at "host name"`.

I made sure to set `Publicly accessible` to `Yes`, but it's still not working. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

(For the settings, I used the default free tier settings.)

Comment: Which security group you are using? Does your RDS security group have permission to your IP?

Comment: @OguzhanAygun I changed it to allow all inbound and outbound connections. Still not working

Comment: Can you try `telnet <host> <port>`? Is your DB networkly reachable? Also your inbound rule is `All traffic` right? Pls make sure your port is permitted in your security group.

Comment: @OguzhanAygun Not sure how I can check telnet... How can I check if the port is permitted?

Comment: Sorry for the newbie questions 

Comment: Can you post your security group's inbound rules' screenshot? Install `telnet` command based on operating system and run `telnet your_aws_postgresql_hosname your_port>` via command line

Comment: @OguzhanAygun Here's the inbound screenshot: https://tppr.me/RVwZa (Getting telnet installed)

Comment: @OguzhanAygun Getting this error when using telnet: `telnet: connect to address "ip address: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host`

Comment: Now it seems like it's hitting the connection, but I'm getting an error saying: `password authentication failed`. I tried resetting the password, but I'm still getting the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243460/discussion-between-oguzhan-aygun-and-jessica).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the question thread, the security group is defined to accept `All Traffic` from all IPv6 addresses `::/0`. Permission for IPv4 address should be added as well. You may want to address All Traffic for `IPv4` address `0.0.0.0/0`.